# How do I toggle Bootstrap toggles based on one?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

**Bootstrap Toggle:**

I want to control 7 other toggles (titled: Sunday -> Saturday).

I have not been able to find the proper way to change the toggle state of one checkbox based on the state of another. How can this be done? It seems the click event and toggle functions are not enough.

```js
$("#check_everything").click(function() {
    if($("#check_everything").bootstrapToggle('on')) {
 $("#Sunday_content_check_all").prop('checked', true).change();
 $("#Monday_content_check_all").prop('checked', true).change();
    $("#Tuesday_content_check_all").bootstrapToggle('on');
    $("#Wednesday_content_check_all").bootstrapToggle('on');
    $("#Thursday_content_check_all").bootstrapToggle('on');
    $("#Friday_content_check_all").bootstrapToggle('on');
 $("#Saturday_content_check_all").bootstrapToggle('on');
    } 
    else {
 $("#Sunday_content_check_all").prop('checked', false).change()
 $("#Monday_content_check_all").prop('checked', false).change()
 $("#Tuesday_content_check_all").bootstrapToggle('off');
 $("#Wednesday_content_check_all").bootstrapToggle('off');
 $("#Thursday_content_check_all").bootstrapToggle('off');
 $("#Friday_content_check_all").bootstrapToggle('off');
 $("#Saturday_content_check_all").bootstrapToggle('off');
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<input  type= "checkbox" 
        checked data-toggle= "toggle" 
        id= 'check_everything' 
        name= 'check_everything'
        data-onstyle= "success" 
        data-offstyle= "warning" 
        data-size= "small"
        data-on= "Yes" 
        data-off= "No">
```

> Please add a comment, if more code block has to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Reference them by class instead of id.

```
$( "div.tumble" ).toggleClass( "bounce" );
```